# I can ping my gateway but I can't access internet and LAN

Tags: networking, server

I was trying to make my server IP static so I changed my /etc/network/interfaces to this:

```
    auto lo eth0
    iface lo inet loopback
    iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.1.1.10
    netmask 255.0.0.0
    gateway 10.1.1.1
```

Now I can't access my LAN. My Samba server was working fine before this change and now nobody in LAN can see it. I can ping my gateway (10.1.1.1) but I can't access internet.

Route command: `route -n`

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric    Ref Use       Iface
default         10.1.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0         0     0       eth0
10.0.0.0        *               25.0.0.0        U     0         0     0       eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000      0     0       eth0
```

---

**UPDATE:**

After restarting my server I can see my samba folders from other computers. Now the only problem that remains is that I can't access internet from it.

Comment: what does the command `route` in the command line tell you?

Comment: Your dns are? `smbd` is up, `nmbd` is up?

Comment: First line: default  10.1.1.1   0.0.0.0   UG   0    0    0   eth0 Second line: 10.0.0.0    *  255.0.0.0     U    0    0    0   eth0  Third line: link-local   *  255.255.0.0   U    1000 0    0   eth0    My DNS: 200.175.189.139 and smbd and nmbd are running

Comment: Hi! Correct me if I'm wrong..  Why is your IP address and gateway the same?? You can't have same IP addresses on two different devices under the same LAN/Subnet. Please clarify on that and about the network a bit. BTW, add the output for `route -n` by **editing** your question. Its quiet difficult to read when you add as a comment. :)

Comment: Ops it was a mistype in my discription. Sorry, my IP is 10.1.1.10 and the gateway is 10.1.1.1.

Comment: Please [**edit**](http://askubuntu.com/posts/475742/edit) your question and post the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Can you ping outside of your intranet?

Comment: The problem was the DNS. I was using the wrong DNS. I don't know why this outdated DNS was working and now it's not working but anyway thanks for your help. Can't believe it was something so simple like that.

Comment: I'm sorry for the typo comments but are you basically looking into the output and typing it here?? Because I see the mask is incorrect on the second line of your output. Having said that, could you also post the exact output for `ifconfig` without making any changes to it. This will help us to assist better. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You entered the same IP address as the server's address and your gateway. That's probably wrong and if your router's/gateway's IP address is really 10.1.1.1 you now have two devices with the same IP address in your net segment.

I suppose you want to change the server's IP to 10.1.1.2 or 10.1.1.10, depending on your network plan, leaving the address of the gateway to 10.1.1.1

Also, a subnet mask of 255.0.0.0 seems to be horribly, unnecessary big. It's not really a problem, but in the long run you can run into problems with that setting, e.g. if you want to set up some kind of routed VPN. You probably want it to be 255.255.255.0. Check the subnet mast settings on your gateway and set the same on your server.

Comment: It was a mistype in my description. Sorry for that. The way it is in my interface file is address 10.1.1.10 and gateway 10.1.1.1. I fixed my description.

Comment: oh, okay. Can you ping an IP address outside your network? E.g. `8.8.8.8` (Google Public DNS)? Just to rule out DNS problems.

Comment: Hi! Subnet is always a subnet and it won't make any issues at all though the IP's are too much for a smaller network. VPN won't make any change to the subnet as that is why there're plenty of techniques which can be applied. :)

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer because it was thanks to the 8.8.8.8 ping that made me see why it was not working.

Comment: Good to hear! May I ask, what the problem was? For future reference... @Subnet: It's not a problem, that's right. But for instance if you try to connect to a routed OpenVPN tunnel, chances are, that either the network subnet or the VPN tunnel net lies in the 10.0.0.0/8 range and then you have a problem :) But you're right, it's not related to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my ubuntu server, i can ping the gateway but not internet.
I solved the problem like this:

-sudo systemctl restart networking